# Error en Controlador al subir varias imagenes a la vez

Tags: laravel, fileupload

Intento subir varias imágenes a la vez y lo que es subirla al servidor la sube pero solo guarda el nombre de la primera en la base de datos las otras la redimensiona y las guarda en la carpeta pero no inserta el nombre en la base de datos a que se puede deber ??

**Formulario**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'posts.store','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) }}
{{ Form::hidden('di', 'di') }}
{{ Form::label('image', 'Imagen') }}
{!! Form::file('profile_image[]', array('multiple' => true)) !!}
 {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
       {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {

   $post = Post::create($request->all());
   $files = $request->file('profile_image');
   foreach ((array) $files as $file)
{

     if($file) {
         //get filename with extension
         $filenamewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();

         //get filename without extension
         $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

         //get file extension
         $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

         //filename to store
         $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
         $post->fill(['file' => $filenametostore])->save();

         //Upload File
         $file->storeAs('public/images', $filenametostore);
         $file->storeAs('public/images/mini', $filenametostore);
         $file->storeAs('public/images/minin', $filenametostore);
         //Resize image
         $thumbnailpath = public_path('storage/images/mini/'.$filenametostore);
         $img = Image::make($thumbnailpath)->resize(null, 200, function($constraint) {
             $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
           $img->save($thumbnailpath);
             //Resize image perfil
             $thumbnailpat = public_path('storage/images/minin/'.$filenametostore);
             $imgn = Image::make($thumbnailpat)->resize(null, 200, function($constraint) {
                 $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->resizeCanvas(200, 200 );

         $imgn->save($thumbnailpat);}
}
         return back()->with('info', 'Foto añadida correctamente');

 }
```

Comment: Creo que error esta exactamente en este código pero no doy con la solución....    [code]$filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;  $post->fill(['file' => $filenametostore])->save();[code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tambien debes introducir el

```
$post = Post::create($request->all());
```

En un foreach